# Change colorPrimary and colorAccent via reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-theme

I'm trying to change `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` programmatically, but I can't found any methods related with them, such as `setThemeColorPrimary(int color)`. The only way I found is change it via [Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html). But, I can't find `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` fields to be reflected.

So, *how can I change `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` programmatically?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your intent to do so? Why don't you set another color programmatically?

Comment: @ThomasR., I want to change `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` at runtime, so that other Android widgets change their color too, for example `FloatingActionButton`'s color and `ViewPager`'s edge effect color. If I use many theme options in `styles.xml`, this can make my apk bigger.

Comment: Edge effect color can be overridden by `android:edgeEffectColor`. Then it can be changed at runtime via reflection, see this class https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/master/android/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/widget/XpEdgeEffect.java.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know that's not possible you can't access colorAccent and colorPrimary fields that's not how Android resources compile process works.

There is no such thing as Theme.colorPrimary , to access Theme atributes you need to use `obtainStyledAtributtes()` or similar technique.

The only way i know to do it programatically is by using `setTheme()` method or using a `ContextThemeWrapper()`. Both ways need you to have multiple style declaration in XML.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no way to override theme attributes!**

---

1) If you don't want to update every view manually, read on.

2) If having predefined sets of primary and accent colors is OK for you, read on.

Have a couple of predefined theme overlays with primary and accent color specified:

```
<style "ThemeOverlay.MyApp.Red" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#880000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00ffff</item>
</style>

<style "ThemeOverlay.MyApp.Blue" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#0000ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000088</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item>
</style>

<!-- Green, orange, etc. -->
```

Now you can wrap any context and override just these three attributes by

```
Context newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_MyApp_*);
```

This is good enough for inflating views or creating them manually.

How to make it automatic for all your activities? Create a `BaseActivity` which all your activities will extend. This activity will update it's theme like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
    final String themeColor = prefs.getString("themeColor", ""); // Non-null!
    final int themeResId;
    switch (themeColor) {
        "BLUE":
            themeResId = R.style.ThemeOverlay_MyApp_Blue;
        default:
            themeResId = R.style.ThemeOverlay_MyApp_Red;
    }
    setTheme(themeResId);

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // etc.
}
```

Where `themeResId` is a resource ID of one of theme overlays defined above. I'm assuming the color theme is a user preference in your app and you store a string like `"RED"` or `"BLUE"` which you can translate to the theme resource ID at runtime. DO NOT store the resource ID to preferences, the IDs change across builds.